# Get the name for Apache Avro's generic record field?

Tags: c++, avro

I'm using Avro in C++ using generic data objects.

Assuming the schema is the same as in the examples:

```
{
    "type": "record", 
    "name": "cpx",
    "fields" : [
        {"name": "re", "type": "double"},    
        {"name": "im", "type" : "double"}
     ]
}
```

I can get the `GenericRecord' and`GenericDatum` like this:

```
const avro::GenericRecord& r = datum.value<avro::GenericRecord>();
const avro::GenericDatum& f0 = r.fieldAt(0);
std::string field0name = ???; // should be "re"
```

How do I get the field `f0`'s name that is specified in the schema? In this example, it should return `"re"`.

Answer (score 2):

First grab the schema pointer and then access the name:

```
std::string field0name = r.schema()->nameAt(0);
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it's correct. Thanks.